# DockerDesktop is unable to detect a Hypervisor

Tags: docker

Hardware assisted virtualization and data protect execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS.

hi guys my eng no good much , i am learning for run node some crypto currency node on docker !

how i setup enable virtualization enable BIOS ?
And Set up TCP/IP Allow Access ?